# Is there a way using HTML in Chrome to change the navigation bar color in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, google-chrome

I have an HTML website and I'm currently making it mobile. Is it possible to change the color of the navigation bar (at the bottom with the 3 buttons) in Android when you're in Chrome? Any help would be greatly appreciated as the white navigation bar doesn't go well with my site's navy blue theme. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am looking for it now myself.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this feature is [not currently supported](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=797527) by chrome. Please comment in the thread if you want some movement on the issue.

Comment: Not sure how this ended up in the VLQ queue - this appears to answer the question. The answer is that what the OP's trying to achieve can't be done. I'm not an expert in this subject, but based on the linked bug report it also appears to be accurate. I'm voting "Looks OK" and +1 on this one.

Answer (score -1):

Write a specific css file for all the rules you want to enable in a chrome browser
Add all the css rules in `@media not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)` Media query to enable the effects only in mobile.
Use the following javascript code to use the chrome css file:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase().indexOf('CHROME') > -1)
{
     var chromeCss = document.createElement("link");

     chromeCss.rel = "stylesheet";
     chromeCss.href = "chromeMobile.css";

     document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(chromeCss);
}
```

Refer [this](http://browserhacks.com/) website for more browser specific hacks.

In case you were referring to change the color of chrome's address bar,put below code in the if statement:

```
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.name = "theme-color";
meta.content = "";//Color code
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
```

Comment: That doesnt answer op's question of how to set chrome's own address bar's color

Comment: @PatrickEvans The question was to change the color of the navigation bar (of a website) not the address bar.

Comment: Navigation bar / address bar is the same thing

Comment: @PatrickEvans I don't think address bar and navigation bar are two same things.<br>An address bar displays the address of a web page where as a navigation bar is a GUI used to navigate across a website. <br> Links:  [link Address Bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_bar) [link Navigation Bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigation_bar)

Comment: Sorry, I think that there's a bit of confusion here - I want to change all of Android's navigation bar (the one at the bottom of the screen with the 3 buttons), I was asking if this was possible. Thanks Again.